# Which usb_modeswitch.d file do I need to use?

Tags: 10.04, usb-drive, automount, usb-modeswitch

How do I configure `usb_modeswitch` on `Ubuntu 10.04`?

When the device is pluged in `lsusb` gives:

```
oshirowanen@laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 19d2:0103 ONDA Communication S.p.A.
```

When I eject the device manually to get it to be recognised as a modem, `lsusb` gives:

```
oshirowanen@laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 19d2:0031 ONDA Communication S.p.A. ZTE MF636
```

So then I searched for `19d2` and got:

```
oshirowanen@laptop:~$ sudo updatedb && locate 19d2
/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:0053
/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:2000
/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:2000:uPr=USB_ZTE
/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:2000:uPr=ZTE_CDMA
/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:fff5
/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:fff6
```

So it seems there is no `usb_modeswitch.conf` file in ubuntu 10.04, instead I get these files in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d`

Do I need to use one of these `19d2` files, if so, which one and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the 2 packages related to `usb_modeswitch`

```
usb-modeswitch
usb-modeswitch-data
```

Please check if both are installed.

`/etc/usb-modeswitch.conf` is part of `usb-modeswitch` as you can see here:

[image: im2]

I got here by opening `synaptic`, searching for modeswitch, clicking `usb-modeswitch` and then clicking `properties` and `installed files`.

1 thing: I am using 11.04. 
In 10.04 you might have to install your own config file. If you did install from synaptic and it still does not work this [topic](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?p=4171&sid=8943633690dac53cd27740ac58fe5449) suggests installing from source: [usb-modeswitch](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/usb-modeswitch) and [usb-modeswitch-data](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/usb-modeswitch-data/20100127-1) (but you are on your own here ;) ).

Regarding the edit: [see this topic on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9719991&postcount=18)

> I'll summarise what I did here for the benefit of others:
>
> 1. I purchased a '3' ZTE MF112 dongle
> 2. I plugged it in. `lsusb` gives `19d2:0103`
> 3. `sudo aptitude install usb-modeswitch`
>    4.`sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/zte_eject.rules`
>
>    ```
>      SYSFS{idVendor}=="19d2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0103", RUN+="/usr/bin/eject %k", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
>    ```
> 4. reboot
> 5. `lsusb` gives `19d2:0031`
> 6. Using **NetworkManager > Edit Connections > Mobile Broadband**, I set up the dongle to access 3's network.
>
> I can now connect whenever I plug in the dongle, provided there  is
> good mobile coverage.

Comment: thanks, that was very useful.  Please see my updated question above.

Comment: @oshirowanen \o/ \o/